# MiniMagick - add texture to image

Tags: imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

Given:

A texture [image: texture] and a photograph (with no transparent background) [image]

How do I give the photograph the texture?

To be specific, I want the following steps:

1. Tile the texture. From [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22860), I have: `convert -size 1056x576 tile:Castillo_001.gif Castillo_tiled.gif`
2. Invert the result.
3. Do a composite with the photograph equivalent to the "Color Dodge" blending mode in Photoshop.

Any clues for MiniMagick? Or any clue for the answer in ImageMagick?

Thanks a bunch.

**Answer**

ImageMagick:

```
convert IMG_1970.JPG \( -size 2816x1584 tile:background.png -negate \) -compose ColorDodge -composite out.jpg
```

Full answer:

```
  # I just negatived the background already
  img = MiniMagick::Image.open(File.join('IMG_1970.JPG'))
  background = MiniMagick::Image.open(File.join('background_negative.png'))
  background.combine_options do |c|
    c.size "#{img['width']}x#{img['height']}"
    c.tile background.path
  end

  img = img.composite(background) do |c|
    c.compose "ColorDodge"
  end
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the images you want to apply the texture to? Could you be more specific on what you mean with _"give the other image that texture"_? Do the images have a transparent background and you want to show the texture only on the background or do you want to apply the texture on the whole image?

Comment: thanks for asking :). i wasn't perfectly sure, but I edited it and made a more precise question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in creating the texture image with the `tile:` format. Simply apply [-negate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#negate) option to invert the result. After which, a simple compose & composite command to apply the "Color Dodge" effect to any given image. See the [Compose Examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#light) article.

```sh
convert \( -size 1056x576 tile:Castillo_001.gif -negate \) \
        source_image.jpg -compose Lighten -composite out_image.jpg
```

Comment: awesome. i got `convert IMG_1970.JPG \( -size 2816x1584 tile:background.png -negate \) -compose ColorDodge -composite out.jpg`

now figuring out converting to MiniMagick, if I get that, it's solved :) Thanks.

Comment: It might be more effort then it's worth using MiniMagick. If you have your command already, just use `Subexec.run`.

Comment: got it in MiniMagick. couldn't of done it without you though. so.